# On causality in physics: is the concept of cause an operational concept in physics?

Tags: causality

This is a broad question motivated by philosophical interests. I hope it will not be considered as off topic.

What I am looking for is a technical answer reflecting the standard conception of nowadays physics.

Let me give some details regarding the context.

Traditionnaly, since Hume I think ,  the distinction betweeen mathematics and natural sciences ( like physics) has been made in the following way:

- mathematics deals with "relations of ideas" that are purely logical
- natural science deals with truth of facts, involving causal relations ( that cannot be reduced to logoical ones), there is ( said Hume) no logical link betweeen " temperature is below zero" and " water has frozen".

My question is not on the logical status of physical-science  truths, but on the role of causality in physics.

I suppose physicists cannot prevent themselves from thinking ( privately) of natural phenomena in terms of causality. But is causality an official concept in physics, a concept having an official theoretical status?

One problem I see is that the language of physics is mathematical, and it seems difficult to translate the ideas of cause and effect in a mathematical languege.

More generally, are physicists interested in problems relating to causality?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3871/50583

Comment: If your axioms include "temperature is below zero" implies " water has frozen", then there is a logical relation between the two.